# QGIS Georeferencer add point tool doesn't function

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

Using the Georeferener, after selecting the add point tool (to add a GCP) I am unable to place a CGP onto the image. Clicking the mouse pointer does not add a GCP as is has done when I've used previous versions. It just doesn't seem to function.

I'm running QGIS 2.14.3 Essen on a Lenovo thinkpad running Windows 10.

I have successfully georeferenced many images before. However trying with a number of images, JPG and BMP the add point tool does nothing.

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: It works fine on QGIS 2.14.15. Try to update your QGIS. It may solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue. Maybe it is similar. When I clicked the map to create the point, the window wasn't popping up. A simple reboot fixed it, but then it happened again after a while. I found that the window was actually popping up behind the georeferencer window. Hope this helps.